# How to use the implicit function scheme on $T(z) = 1 + zT(z)^2$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, analytic-combinatorics

> We know that the OGF $T(z)$ of convex polygonials satisfies the relation
> $$T(z) = G(z,T(z)) := 1 + zT(z)^2.$$
> Why does $G(z,w)$ not satisfy the requirements of the implicits function scheme? Find a function $H(z,T(z))$ so that the implicit function scheme is applicable.
>
> Remark: You can find the relevant section from the Flajolet & Sedgewick book page 467, 468 below.

I know that $$T(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$$

and that $T(z)$ is analytic in $\lvert z \rvert < 1/4$. However, I am confused on how to check the  conditions of the implicit function scheme on $G(z,T(z))$, because I do not see how to obtain the coefficients $g_{m,n}$. Could you please explain this to me?

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what is $G(z, w)$ in your example?

Comment: If I am not mistaken this is meant to be $G(z,w) = G(z, T(z))$, right?

Comment: No: $G(z, w)$ is a polynomial or power series in two variables $z$ and $w$, such that when you plug $T(z)$ into it for $w$ to get your RHS.  So what is the polynomial or power series in two variables $z, w$ such that when you plug in $T(z)$ for $w$, you get the RHS of your equation?

Comment: Ah, so $G(z,w) = 1 + zw^2$?

Comment: Yes.  Now you should be able to go on I hope?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to expand $1+zw^2$. The fact that it is bivariate confuses me a bit.

Comment: Suppose I had a power series $F(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} f_n x^n$, and I told you that, in my particular case, in fact $F(x) = 1 + 2x^2 + x^3$.  From that, can you tell me what are $f_0$, $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_{17}$, $f_{42}$ (for example)?  Then do the same exercise with $G(z, w)$, comparing the general form and the particular polynomial you care about.